# How can i get the address of a function in memory?

Tags: c, elf, stack, objdump

I am currently completing a CTF exercise where i must attempt to overwrite a function pointer on the stack through a buffer overflow here is the code:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *gets(char *);

void complete_level() {
  printf("Congratulations, you've finished :-) Well done!\n");
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct {
    char buffer[64];
    volatile int (*fp)();
  } locals;

  locals.fp = NULL;
  gets(locals.buffer);

  if (locals.fp) {
    printf("calling function pointer @ %p\n", locals.fp);
    fflush(stdout);
    locals.fp();
  } else {
    printf("function pointer remains unmodified :~( better luck next time!\n");
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

The code will get input using the vulnerable `gets()` function and store it inside the buffer called `buffer`.

Since `buffer` is the largest variable in the struct it will allow me to overwrite variables below it on the stack. The next variable is the function pointer called `fp`.

In order to overwrite `fp` i will need to find the address of the `complete_level` function in memory. Then write "A" 64 times, then write the functions address.

**The problem i have is that i cannot find the address of the function.**

So far i have tried `objdump` however that gives me a offset and not the full address:

```
objdump -M intel -d 3 | grep complete_level
    1184:   80 3d 8d 2e 00 00 00    cmp    BYTE PTR [rip+0x2e8d],0x0        # 4018 <completed.0>
    11ac:   c6 05 65 2e 00 00 01    mov    BYTE PTR [rip+0x2e65],0x1        # 4018 <completed.0>
00000000000011c9 <complete_level>:
```

Here is an output of the executable under the `file` command:

```
3: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
BuildID[sha1]=11a5f76e0d40b7f4fdc53d4dd60faac9f9e405be, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Why is it not showing the full address? Also how can i get the full address of the function `complete_level`?

Comment: The full address will be when the program is loaded into the memory. You have PIE executable here